# How do I upload image from Google Sheets to Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

As the title suggests, I currently have codes taking a screenshot of a website and putting it on my Google Sheets. My question is how to then transfer that image to the presentation? The image might change so it would be better if can be dynamically changed. I saw the class `ReplaceAllShapesWithImageRequest` but there were not a lot of examples, and they used URL instead of cell from Google Sheets. Thank you for the help!

*Edit*

Also there might be more images(around 9), and there are placeholders in the slides right now, but how am I able to target specific slides for specific images to fit something like this
[image]

Where the numbers 01-08 will be the images.
Thank you for the help.

**Edit 2**
The following is the code for snapping the screenshot

```
function snapScreenshot() {
  //specify where I want the image to be
  var row = 11;
  var col = 2;
  var siteUrl = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue()
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" + encodeURIComponent(siteUrl) + "&key=" + pageSpeedApiKey;
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var obj = JSON.parse(res);
  var imgData = obj.lighthouseResult.audits['final-screenshot'].details.data;
  var strImage = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "")
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(strImage), "image/jpeg", "sample.jpeg");
  sheet.insertImage(blob, 1, 29);

   for (var i=0; i< obj.lighthouseResult.audits["screenshot-thumbnails"].details.items.length; i++) {
    var imgData = obj.lighthouseResult.audits["screenshot-thumbnails"].details.items[i].data;
    var strImage = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "")
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(strImage), "image/jpeg", "sample.jpeg");
    sheet.insertImage(blob, 1, 20+(i*6))
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script? And, is your question `My question is how to then transfer that image to the presentation?`? If my understanding is correct, what is "Edit" section?

Comment: @Tanaike The basis of my question is `how to transfer the screenshots(images) I took of the website to a specific section(number 01-08) of a specific slide(will have 2 slides that need images)`. Which part of my script do you need me to provide? I have done the screenshotting part but have just been googling how to transfer the image. I hope that clears up the questions. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your script. From your script, in your situation, it is required to copy the image from Spreadsheet to Slides? For example, how about directly putting the image to Slides? But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So this is not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike If the image can be changed every time the script is runned depending on the URL then it is fine to put the image directly to Slides.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in your situation, the script can be run by the time-driven trigger. By this, the image can be updated by a cycle. If you can directly put the image to Slides using your script, I thought that it can be simpler.

Comment: @Tanaike How do I directly put the image to Slides instead? Also, instead of it being a time-driven trigger, wouldn't it be better to run the script from Spreadsheet as I have to collect other data from Lighthouse? The problem would be the event type I think. Does form submit include buttons? I currently have a button made and assigned a script to generate slides. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you wanted to copy the image from Spreadsheet to Slides. I deeply apologize that my suggestion was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: @Tanaike It is not necessary to copy the image from Spreadsheet if I can just take the images from pagespeed insights API and put them on the slides directly as you suggested. I can set the function to run when a button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when you click a button on Spreadsheet, the image is retrieved using your current script, and the retrieved image is directly put to Slides. In this case, your goal might be achieved. How about this direction?

Comment: @Tanaike This direction sounds perfect, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. And also, when the button is clicked, the retrieved image can be put to both Spreadsheet and Slides. By this, you can also see the images on Spreadsheet. In this case, I thought that the script might become simpler rather than the image is retrieved from Spreadsheet and it is put to Slides. About this, if you cannot modify your script, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike The script can be modified, do not worry about it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike The issue is technically not resolved. I don't know how to put the image directly on Slides and position them according to the image above. Would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the image above`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike Basically how do I put the image directly on Slides and position them side by side. I have changed the image above, as well as the code in my post. Img1-Img8 is where I want the `thumbnail images` to be.

Comment: @Tanaike So I kind of have an idea of how to put the image directly on Slides but need some help. My current presentation url is `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/xxxxxx/edit#slide=id.g106a1744bd9_0_53`. I believe `xxxxxx` would be the presentation id, but would the slide id be `id.g106a1744bd9_0_53` or `g106a1744bd9_0_53`. Currently using `presentation.getSlideById(id)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue of your next question from your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to try to understand your current issue of your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of figure it out thanks to Tanaike's direction. Instead of getting the image from pagespeed insights api, put it on Sheets **then** put it on Slide, I directly put the images on the Slide instead.

```
function snapScreenshot(presentationId) {
  var row = 11;
  var col = 2;
  var siteUrl = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue()
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" + encodeURIComponent(siteUrl) + "&key=" + pageSpeedApiKey;
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var obj = JSON.parse(res);
  var imgData = obj.lighthouseResult.audits['final-screenshot'].details.data;
  var strImage = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "")
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(strImage), "image/jpeg", "sample.jpeg");
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId)
  var page = presentation.getSlideById(slide_id)
  var position = {left:230, top: 87};
  var size = {width: 600, height: 220}
  page.insertImage(blob, position.left, position.top, size.width, size.height)
```